# Understanding Kattis Path Crossing

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am currently stuck on this question while self-learning algorithms with Kattis Open: https://open.kattis.com/problems/pathcrossings

I have some trouble understanding what the output is all about and coming up with a proper algorithm.

Here are some questions I have:
What does same ai mean? Does it mean the same player? Or will there be duplicate pairs?
What does ascending order of bi mean?

Any hints and explanations are appreciated :)

Comment: This question is unrelated to C++. Questions on Stackoverflow should be self-contained. That means they should be answerable and understandable without external links.

Comment: Ascending order of bi means that `bi` < `bj` for `i` < `j`. Same `ai` means that player `ai` can meet player `bi` and `bj`. You should output e.g. `3 6` and then `3 9`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We shouldn't have to go off-site to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

> What does same *a<sup>i</sup>* mean?

Your output is the total number of distinct (unique) pairs of players that have crossed paths, then a list of the pairs of these players, using id numbers `a[i]` and `b[i]`. `a` and `b` are different players (a player cannot cross paths with themselves) and `i` means the `i`-th pairing, as in an array. The output is sorted so the test harness can properly validate it. You sort by `a[i]` and whenever there are two  different pairs that have the same `a[i]` break ties by the `b[i]` player id.

As an example, imagine player 4 (`a[i]` and `a[i+1]`) crossed paths with player 5 (`b[i]`) and player 67 (`b[i+1]`). The output would be (in part)

```
4 5
4 67
```

rather than

```
4 67
4 5
```

because `5 < 67`.

Keep in mind, player 4 will be printed first because `a[i] < b[i]` for all `i` you print. That means the following are not valid output for these pairs:

```
4 67
5 4
```

```
5 4
67 4
```

etc.

> Does it mean the same player?

No, a player cannot cross paths with themselves. So the following is illegal:

```
16 16
```

that is, player 16 cannot cross paths with themselves.

> Or will there be duplicate pairs?

No, all crossings are distinct. So if players 12 and 18 cross, you just print one pairing with `a[i] < b[i]`:

```
12 18
```

rather than

```
18 12
12 18
```

which breaks the `a[i] < b[i]` and no duplicate pairs (in any order) rules.

> What does ascending order of *b<sup>i</sup>* mean?

It means when you have a tie on `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` and use `b[i]` values as the tie breaker, you print this:

```
4 5
4 15
```

not

```
4 15
4 5
```

Keep in mind: `a[i]` can also be a `b[i]` in some other row of the output. Let's say player 4 and player 16 crossed paths, and player 4 and player 2 crossed paths. You should output

```
2 4
4 16
```

Here, player 4 is in positions `b[0]` and `a[1]`, so the `a` and `b` language is just there to explain the ordering specification within a row, and how to handle duplicate `a[i]` values between adjacent rows.

I've ignored the total count of crossings in these examples, so the above would be

```
2
2 4
4 16
```

in totality, because there were 2 distinct crossings.

---

As for the algorithm, I took advantage of the constraint that there will be no more than 5 pings within a given 10-second interval. This allowed me to sort the input data by time, then loop over it, scanning up to 5 steps forward for each index to hunt for a pair. Any matched pairs were added to a set to remove duplicates, then sorted and printed.

This approach wasn't especially fast, 1.61s in Ruby (I see there are Python solutions as fast as 0.56s), so there's still room for optimization.