# Kattis Sorting AlgorithmPath Crossings

Tags: sorting, data-structures

Does anyone have a fast algorithmic/pythonic approach to the problem below?
https://open.kattis.com/problems/pathcrossings
I would like to sort the list firstly by players and then by time. However, I'm unsure of how to compare -10 <= t <= 10 across two list.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of those sites to test your own knowledge? If you ask for a solution you could as well simply not solve it. Comparing two lists often means you have a double for loop, one for each list so you can compare all combinations of indices

Comment: See [Understanding Kattis Path Crossing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73435177/understanding-kattis-path-crossing/73818781#73818781)